# Selenium Webdriver how to avoid using `"no-sandbox"` mode for ChormeDriver to prevent timeouts

Tags: c#, selenium-chromedriver

In order to avoid the error shown below given by Selenium Webdriver when using a `ChromeDriver` I added the the `no-sandbox` parameter to the options given when instantiating it.

> The HTTP request to the remote WebDriver server for URL
>   http://localhost:54482/session/ce96135773ce0b3aaca691727b25f087/timeouts
>   timed out after 60 seconds.
>       ---- System.Net.WebException : The operation has timed out.

I tried looking on the web to understand *why* this is needed but I did not find anything that helped me understand the reasons for the `ChromeDriver` to timeout when it's in sandbox mode.

I would also like to be able to find a workaround as I find this parameter to be very confusing.

Does anyone know the reason behind the need for this parameter and an eventual workaround ?

My selenium version is `3.12.0`
My Chrom.WebDriver version is `2.38.0`

Comment: Have tried passing in the timeout parameter when creating the ChromeDriver?

Comment: Yes, i have. The parameter gets ignored entirely

Comment: Which version of the selenium library and chromeDriver are you using? Can you post the code as well?

Comment: I updated my question. Here are the versions (both latest): 
My selenium version is `3.12.0`
My Chrom.WebDriver version is `2.38.0`

Comment: Regarding the timeout, seems like there is a bug and there is an issue open in selenium repository https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/4942

Comment: Good to know. Thanks for the link :-)